# Ubuntu kept freezing and can't boot after entering Win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, shutdown

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.10 alongside with Win 10 using a USB. I disabled the "fast start". I kept "secure boot" enabled.

1. When I boot from USB, I first clicked "try Ubuntu". After the trial, I clicked the restart in Ubuntu, but my computer froze! I have to press the power button for 5s to shut down my laptop.
2. Then I start installing Ubuntu. At the screen "choose you time zone", I clicked "quit" as I want to install it at a later time. Then my computer froze. Again, power button to shut down.
3. I installed Ubuntu. I selected installing the third party software option as my laptop has Nvidia GPU with a 4K screen. In the end a message says "installation complete, please restart". I clicked "OK", and then froze and power button to force shut down!
4. I could see Ubuntu option as my first boot choice when I started the laptop. I entered Ubuntu and can open web browser and do other things. But, when I clicked shutdown or restart, it froze!
5. I selected to enter Win 10 once. Then I can never be back to Ubuntu. Each time I restart Win 10, it automatically goes to Win 10 without giving me the choice for Ubuntu as before.

Please help. Why does it freeze at so many occasions? Shall I disable "secure boot" or try Easy BCD software?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems myself: I am still keeping the security boot enabled.

1. type the following command in Win 10 command prompt:

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

This will give me the ubuntu option when I start the laptop.

2. The freezing problem after clicking "shut down" seems to be related with the Nvidia driver. I followed the first answer in the post :
   [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I used to use X.org driver, now I'm using Nvidia driver 390 (proprietary): there are Nvidia 396, 410, 415 available in my "Software & Updates", all of which are open source.